# Index goes out of range when trying to read large excel file

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

Hello i am trying to create a file that reads from a excel file 125000 ids and usernames which have to be delimited, create tokens based on that and then creating confirmations links. The problem is that at a certain point in time (after more than 30 000 iterations) the index goes out of range for no concrete reason.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ExcelDataReader;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace CoRegApp
{
    public class Excel_Creation
    {
        static string[] tokens;

        string emailConfirmationLink;
        public List<string> EmailsList = new List<string>();
        public List<string> userList = new List<string>();
        //Create a variable of the token date

        public Excel_Creation() { }

        public void readExcel()
        {
            string filepath = "batch2.xlsx";
            var tokenDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).Date;
            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream))
                {
                    DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                    DataTable firstTable = result.Tables[0];

                    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (DataRow dr in firstTable.Rows)
                    {
                        object[] arr = dr.ItemArray;
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string input = ((Convert.ToString(arr[i])));
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
                            {
                                tokens = input.Split(';');
                                for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                                {
                                    string token = EncryptionHelper.CreateToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokenDate);
                                    emailConfirmationLink = "https://blablaconfirmation/Validate?token=" + token + "&blablavalidation2";
                                    EmailsList.Add(emailConfirmationLink);
                                    userList.Add((Convert.ToString(arr[i])));
                                    Console.WriteLine(emailConfirmationLink);
                                }
                            }

                            //tokens =().Split(';'));
                        }
                    }
                    excelReader.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void MapToExcel()
        {
            //start excel
            Excel.Application excapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            //if you want to make excel visible 
            excapp.Visible = true;

            //create a blank workbook
            var workbook = excapp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

            //Not done yet. You have to work on a specific sheet - note the cast
            //You may not have any sheets at all. Then you have to add one with NsExcel.Worksheet.Add()
            var sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1]; //indexing starts from 1

            //now the list
            string cellName;
            int counter = 1;
            foreach (string item in EmailsList)
            {
                cellName = "B" + counter.ToString();
                var range = sheet.get_Range(cellName, cellName);
                range.Value2 = item.ToString();
                ++counter;
            }

            string cellName2;
            int counterB = 1;
            foreach (string item in userList)
            {
                cellName2 = "A" + counterB.ToString();
                var range = sheet.get_Range(cellName2, cellName2);
                range.Value2 = item.ToString();
                ++counterB;
            }
        }//end of mapping method
    }
}
```

Comment: I can guarantee you that there is definitely a concrete reason. Debug your program, look at the values at the time of breakage and compare that to any assumptions you make in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have reused the looping variable "i" within the loop of "i":

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        ...
                            for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

The clue is that you didn't have to declare the variable for the inner loop. You should always expect to declare your looping variable in the for (or foreach); or you're *probably* doing something wrong.

In this case, what will happen, is that it will enter the outer loop, set "i" to zero, check that i is less than arr.Length; do some other stuff, and if the conditions are right, it will enter the inner loop (which re-sets "i" to zero, checks it is less than 1, does the contents of the inner loop, increments i (because of the inner loop), drops out of that loop, reaches the end of the outer loop, increments i again (so now it's 2), and checks against arr.Length before possibly going round again.

That inner loop is effectively pointless because it will always do it once and only once, so I'd suggest removing that loop, and fixing the references to "i" within it to either be 0, or to stay as "i"; depending on what your intent was (because it's ambiguous which "i" you were trying to refer to).

If I can suggest that you always give your variables names, you may find that it not only helps prevent you doing this; but it will make your code more readable.

If it helps, you can think of a for-loop as being like a while loop that is coded like this...

```
                int i = 0;
                while(i < arr.Length)
                {
                    ...
                    i++;
                }
```

But you have tinkered with "i" in the "..." part.

EDIT: additional:

```
tokens = input.Split(';');
...
string token = EncryptionHelper.CreateToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokenDate);
```

but there is no check of how many items are in tokens before using the indexers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

Actually the issue was kind of dumb. Even if my array will always be resetted to contain only two items of index[0] and [1]. hardcoding it to access those values seems to make the loop go out of bound at some point in time. Don't really know. Thus simply replacing the 
`string token = EncryptionHelper.CreateToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokenDate);` 
with

```
int counter1 = counter;
counter1--;
string token = EncryptionHelper.CreateToken(tokens[counter1], tokens[counter], tokenDate);
```

solved the issue

Comment: I think you still haven't read the last sentence of my answer which will explain the point that you "Don't really know". P.S. are you aware that you can mark something as the answer? I spent time and effort finding 2 faults in your code, while others would look to put your question on hold.

Comment: In case that wasn't clear enough: how do you know there are enough items in the tokens array to use 'counter' value as an index.